# Submit Button not responding in MVC3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have been working on ASP MVC3 but the submit button is not responding and if i use `URL Action` `(<button type="button" class="submitBtnYellow"  id="DateSubmit1" onclick ="location.href='@Html.Action("MarketAdmin", "AdminDashboard",  FormMethod.Post)'" >)` its redirection to `GET` and the model is empty but my `POST` is not working

The controller is as follows

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MarketAdmin(Reports report)
        {
        //my Code 
        return View();
        }

        [OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, Duration = 0)]
         public ActionResult MarketAdmin( )
        {
        //my Code 
        return View();
        }
```

The view is as follows

```
@using XXXX.AdminPortal.Helpers;
@model  XXXX.Domain.Model.Reports
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Reports";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("MarketAdmin", "AdminDashboard", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "AdminDashboard" }))
  {

  <html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
```

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#StartDate2").attr("readonly", "true");

            $("#EndDate2").attr("readonly", "true");

            $("#StartDate2").datepicker({ maxDate: -1 });
            $("#StartDate").datepicker({ maxDate: -1 });
            $("#EndDate2").datepicker({ maxDate: -1 });
            $("#EndDate").datepicker({ maxDate: -1 });

            $('#DateSubmit2').click(function () {
                alert(startDate1); alert(endDate1);
                var startDate1 = $('#StartDate2').datepicker('getDate');
                var endDate1 = $('#EndDate2').datepicker('getDate');


                if (startDate1 == null) {
                    alert("Please enter Start Date.");
                    $("#StartDate2").val("");
                    $("#StartDate2").focus();
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    if (endDate1 == null) {
                        alert("Please enter End Date.");
                        $("#EndDate2").val("");
                        $('#EndDate2').focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (startDate1 >= endDate1) {
                            alert("Start Date should be less the End Date");
                            $("#StartDate2").val("");
                            $('#StartDate2').focus();
                            return false;

                        }
                    }
                }

              //  $("#StartDate").val(startDate1);

                alert(startDate1);
                alert(endDate1);
            });
```

//code continues

```
@*  <div style="border: 1px solid black">*@
   <div>



    </div>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Dashboard</a></li>
         <li><a href="#tabs-2"> XXX</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3"> XXX</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-4">Reports</a></li> 

        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
              <div class ="inlinedate">
                <div class="form-row">

                            @Html.LabelWithStyleFor(model => model.StartDate, new { @class = "text" })
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, new { @class = "inputtext", id = "StartDate2", name = "start_date" })
                        <div class="error">
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
                        </div>
                        @Html.LabelWithStyleFor(model => model.EndDate, new { @class = "text" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate, new { @class = "inputtext", id = "EndDate2" })
                        <div class="error">
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate)
                        </div>


                </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="submitBtnYellow" id="DateSubmit2"> 
                           <span>@Localization.Global.ContactUs_Submit</span>  
                        </button>


            <div id="chart1" style="height: 400px; width: 900px; position: relative"></div>
```

I have tried   but it was redirticting to GET and the model value was empty

Can any one please help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean _i use URL Action_? Nothing in you code indicates you using that. And what is the relevance of including the script for the datepickers (I can't see that it has anything to with the issue)?

Comment: I have a submit button  <button type="submit" class="submitBtnYellow" id="DateSubmit2"> 
                           <span>@Localization.Global.ContactUs_Submit</span>  
                        </button>       and this is not posting  even if i have @using (Html.BeginForm("MarketAdmin", "AdminDashboard", FormMethod.Post, to do a post on submit

Comment: Why does your button have `id="DateSubmit2"`? Do you have a script associated with this?

Comment: Yes,  $('#DateSubmit2').click(function () {..}

Comment: What does it do? Edit you question (you have included a whole lot of irrelevant confusing code and left out the important bits!)

Comment: The above code is already oresent there

Comment: Comment out your script, then try it.

Comment: not classic asp...remove that tag